# Complex Outer Join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table strucutre.

Logic:  If a plant-partnumber combination, SumQty should be lised if it has an entry in @MHL table.

1. I need to list the sum value for plant "11" and "DEF" partnumber combination, I need to list the sum as 50

**CODE**

```
DECLARE @MHL TABLE (LineNumber VarCHAR(5), PartNumber VARCHAR(10), Qty INT)


INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10001','ABC',10)
INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10002','ABC',100)
INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10003','DEF',50)
INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10005','KXY',25)
INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10006','KXY',30)


DECLARE @MHP TABLE (PlantCode VarCHAR(5), LineNumber VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('20','10001')
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('21','10002')
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('80','10005')
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('80','10006')


DECLARE @MasterPLantParts TABLE (PlantCode VarCHAR(5), PartNumber VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('20','ABC')
INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('21','ABC')
INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('96','ABC')
INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('11','DEF')
INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('80','KXY')


SELECT M.PlantCode,M.PartNumber,SumQty
FROM @MasterPLantParts M
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT PartNumber, PlantCode, SUM(Qty) SumQty
     FROM @MHL H
     LEFT OUTER JOIN @MHP p
        on P.LineNumber = H.LineNumber
     GROUP BY PartNumber, PlantCode
    )T
ON T.PartNumber = M.PartNumber
AND T.PlantCode = M.PlantCode
```

**CURRENT RESULT**

[image]

**EXPECTED RESULT**

[image]

**QUESTION**

The QtySum "50" is not coming now. How to do it in SQL Server 2005? It would be great if the approach can work in Oracle 8i also

Note:  Even if there is no record in @MHP I need to get sum from @MHL. But if there is a value in @MHP, get the associated value from @MHP, @MHL relationship

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Why for "11" and "DEF" it is 50, and for "96" and "ABC" it is 0?

Comment: the value for DEF will come if you execute the following statement: `INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('11','10003')`

Comment: @cha is right, you have no relationship between PlantCode and LineNumber, so there is no way to have SQL get to the Part/Qty through any join, unless you start with the QTY and work out, but then the PlantCode will be NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

The following query (which is even simpler than the first one I posted) would get you the desired result. First, all rows from MasterPLantParts are selected (using a LEFT OUTER JOIN). Then, a join is made with MHL. If there were no entries in MHP for a given Plant, then all Lines from MHL are selected for the Plant).

```
select 
  mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, 
  mpp.PartNumber PartNumber,
  sum(MHL.Qty) as SumQty
from MasterPLantParts mpp
left outer join MHP on mpp.PlantCode = MHP.PlantCode
inner join MHL on MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber or (mpp.PartNumber = MHL.PartNumber and MHP.LineNumber is null)
group by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c284/14)</kbd>

**Oracle 8i syntax**:

```
select 
  mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, 
  mpp.PartNumber PartNumber,
  sum(MHL.Qty) as SumQty
from MasterPLantParts mpp, MHP, MHL 
where mpp.PlantCode = MHP.PlantCode(+)
and (MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber or (mpp.PartNumber = MHL.PartNumber and MHP.LineNumber is null))
group by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber;
```

**Reference**:

[Oracle SQL*Plus Pocket Reference](http://oreilly.com/catalog/orsqlpluspr2/chapter/ch01.html)

Comment: Can you please help with Oracel 8i query also so that I can mark it as answer?

Comment: Are you getting an error message on Oracle 8i?  I don't have it available, but this seems like basic SQL that should work.

Comment: @Lijo Please check the updated answer above for the Oracle 8i syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it on any of your dbms, but it should work with minor fixes on both of them.

```
select PlantCode, PartNumber, sum(qty) 
from (
    select x.PlantCode, x.PartNumber, y.Qty 
    from MasterPLantParts x 
    join MHL y 
        on x.PartNumber = y.PartNumber 
    left join MHP z 
        on x.PlantCode = z.PlantCode 
    where z.PlantCode is null 
    union 
    select x.PlantCode, x.PartNumber, z.Qty 
    from MasterPLantParts x 
    join MHP y 
        on x.PlantCode = y.PlantCode 
    join mhl z 
        on y.LineNumber = z.LineNumber
) as T 
group by PlantCode, PartNumber;

PLANTCODE PARTNUMBER 3          
--------- ---------- -----------
11        DEF                 50
20        ABC                 10
21        ABC                100
80        KXY                 55
96        ABC                110
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('91','what ever line number you wan to go here')   
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('11','what ever line number you wan to go here')
```

With out these values in MHP you will always have null values because that's what a Left Outer Join is suppose to do.